# Capybara::Element Not Found

Tags: capybara

I'm working along with the Rspec book as it develops a 'showtime' rails application, which provides information about films. As far as I can tell, I've copied the code exactly (the book's not that great at letting readers know every step to take), but I'm getting this error.

```
Unable to find select box "Release Year" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:6:in `/^I create a movie Caddyshack in the Comedy genre$/'
```

My movie_steps.rb file has this code, which provides users a select box to select the release year, which is the element Capybara can't find.

```
#---
When /^I create a movie Caddyshack in the Comedy genre$/ do
  visit movies_path
  click_link "Add Movie"
  fill_in "Title", :with => "Caddyshack"
  select "1980", :from => "Release Year"
  check "Comedy"
  click_button "Save"
end

Then /^Caddyshack should be in the Comedy genre$/ do
  visit genres_path
  click_link "Comedy"
  response.should contain("1 movie")
  response.should contain("Caddyshack")
end
```

In the movies view, I have this code, which is, as far as I can tell, all i need to implement the select box.

```
<%= form_for @movie do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.label :release_year %>
  <%= f.select :release_year, (1900..2009).to_a.map(&:to_s) %>
  <% @genres.each do |genre| %>
    <label>
      <%=h genre.name %>
      <%= check_box_tag "genres[]", genre.id %>
    </label>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions you could provide.

Comment: Can you give the actual html of the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `select "1980", :from => "Release year"` instead. If you want it to display as "Release Year", then change your label to show as follows:

```
f.label :release_year, "Release Year"
```

Rails automatically formats the label for you using the [humanize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize) method, but you can change it to anything you like.